# How do I pass option to JavaPluginExtension using Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, protoc, protobuf-java

I'm having issue converting these gradle groovy code to kotlin dsl.

```
protobuf {
  protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
      task.builtins {
        java {
          option "lite"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Especially the `option "lite"` in java block.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this with `Kotlin DSL`.

*build.gradle.kts*

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3"
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            it.builtins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `create("java")` might not work always, As in my case I'm using `getByName("java")`. Thanks.

Comment: And also need to add these imports: 
`import com.google.protobuf.gradle.generateProtoTasks

import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protobuf

import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protoc`

Comment: I've found that if you have to use `getByName("")` it means you've already created a task. Should be correct, that would use `create("")` and `getByName("")` depending on the case. As for import, I use `
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*`. And I appreciate your comments.